# Android GalleryView setCallbackDuringFling causes stutter

Tags: android

I tried to use setCallbackDuringFling to update some indicator during Gallery fling and somehow, whenever I set it to (true), it stutters. When I say "stutter", I mean the next image jumps/snaps into view, thus the visual is very jumpy during the fling. Even when I drag it very slowly, the next image shows up, then when it's half way, it snaps into place.

However, if I set it to false (thus onItemSelected still get called but only once when the fling stops), the scrolling/fling is very smooth.

My onItemSelected (see code below) is not intensive at all, thus I suspect the stuttering is caused by something behind the scene.

Any idea to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

```
// Set up Gallery listeners
myGallery.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

    // When scrolling stops, set the indicators
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        ImageView myIV;

        // First reset myCurrentDot
        myIV = (ImageView) findViewById (myDotID[myCurrentDot]);
        myIV.setImageResource(R.drawable.grey);
        // The set the "position" dot to red
        myIV = (ImageView) findViewById (myDotID[position]);
        myIV.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);
        // update myCurrentDot
        myCurrentRedDot = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}); // End Gallery Listener
```

Answer (score 0):

When `setCallbackDuringFling()` is called with `true`, every time an item is selected,  `onItemSelected` is called on your `AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener` instance.

Looking at your code, we can see that `findViewById()` is called twice. Maybe finding the view is a too heavy process. Perhaps, instead of searching the views every time, you can use a view cache mechanism. Just replace your layout ids cache (`myDotID`) by a view cache (`ImageView[] myDotViews`).